# Is there a way to make multiple Shiny picker inputs where the selections must be disjoint?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I'm looking to make some picker inputs in Shiny for each of the 50 states, but I'd like to separate them into three different groups such that no group has the same state. I was just wondering if there was a way to ensure that the three picker inputs didn't both select the same state or if there was perhaps a better way of doing this in R that I was not aware of. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes a bit of work to set up, but you can accomplish that by updating the
available choices for other inputs when one changes. If you only have two or
three inputs that should be linked like this, it may be tempting to just
write out the observers and be done with it. But really, this is a
generalizable pattern, so I think it makes sense to use a helper function
instead. That way, you can link however many inputs you need, and also re-use
the logic in different apps.

All that the helper function needs to know is the IDs of the participating
inputs, and the set of shared choices. It’s not strictly necessary here, but
also making the `choices` reactive lets them dynamically change.

```r
selectPool <- function(inputIds, choices = reactive(NULL)) {
  stopifnot(is.reactive(choices))
  session <- getDefaultReactiveDomain()
  input <- session$input
  
  # Keep track of all selected values in the pool
  alreadySelected <- reactive({
    Reduce(union, lapply(inputIds, \(id) input[[id]]))
  })
  
  # ... and based on that, what's left to select from.
  remainingChoices <- reactive({
    setdiff(choices(), alreadySelected())
  })
  
  # When an input changes, update remaining choices for others
  lapply(inputIds, \(id) {
    observe({
      lapply(setdiff(inputIds, id), \(otherId) {
        otherSelected <- input[[otherId]]
        updateSelectInput(
          session = session,
          inputId = otherId,
          # Anything already selected must remain a choice
          choices = c(remainingChoices(), otherSelected),
          selected = otherSelected
        )
      })
    }) |> bindEvent(input[[id]], ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  })
}
```

Once we’ve taken the time to do that, it’s very straightforward to use in an app:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Star Wars Alliance Builder"),
  selectInput("alliance1", "Alliance 1", NULL, multiple = TRUE),
  selectInput("alliance2", "Alliance 2", NULL, multiple = TRUE),
  selectInput("alliance3", "Alliance 3", NULL, multiple = TRUE),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  selectPool(
    inputIds = c("alliance1", "alliance2", "alliance3"),
    choices = reactive(unique(dplyr::starwars$species))
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

By "picker inputs" I assume you mean `selectInput`/`selectizeInput`.

There are multiple ways you could do this. One way would be to use `updateSelectInput()` to update the reminding inputs after the first/second has been selected. The possible states to choose from would then be all states except the one(s) already selected. This would make it impossible to choose the same state in multiple inputs from the UI.

However, this might be a bit involved for your need. In that case I suggest that you:

- either replace your three inputs with one `selectInput(..., multiple = TRUE)`, and use `validate()` to check that the user has selected exactly three states
- or simply just use `validate()` to throw an error to the user if they have selected the same state more than once in any of the three inputs.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm updating the inputs as you suggested, and I've also incorporated the validate function to make sure the inputs are as we want them!